# Is vuforia's virtual button disable while the imageTarget is lose tracking?

Tags: vuforia

I use “extended tracking” mode for my Vuforia, unity project. And I find a problem that when my ARcamera is losing track of the imageTarget(the objects will still display) but the virtual button will not work any more? So my question do these virtual buttons only work while the ARCamera can recognize the imageTarget?

Answer (score 1):

The virtual buttons are not supposed to work when the target is lost, even when using Extended Tracking feature. This is because virtual buttons work by covering specific features of the target, so if there is no target, it cannot work. Extended Tracking feature allows Vuforia to guess and keep telling you what was the position of the target, based on other means, and it does not recognize the existence of virtual buttons by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can find article about Virtual Buttons on Vuforia Library site [here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Implement-Virtual-Buttons).

There is a paragraph saying:

> The rectangle that you define for the area of a Virtual button should be equal to, or greater than, 10% of the overall target area.  Button events are triggered when a significant proportion of the features underlying the area of the button are concealed from the camera. This can occur when the user covers the button or otherwise blocks it in the camera view. For this reason, the button should be sized appropriately for the source of the action it is intended to respond to. For example, a button that should be triggered by a user's finger needs to be smaller than one that will be triggered by their entire hand.

Answer (score 0):

The image target is lose tracking 
=> Assets => Editor =>Vuforia => Image Target ='your License Manager' => ' your photo' => change texture type into sprite 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF14X.png)